# Fastest way to send multiple char array over TCP

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm working on a webserver framework in C++ mostly for my own understanding, but I want to optimize it as well.

My question is is it faster to write multiple char arrays to the TCP connection for every html response or to spend the time to concatenate up front and only write to the TCP connection once. I was thinking about benchmarking it, but I am not quite sure how to go about it.

This is my first post on stackoverflow, although I have benefitted from the website very often!

Thanks!

Here is what I am talking about for sending many char arrays individually. The alternate would be concatenate all of these char arrays into one char array then sending that.

```
int main() {
    sockaddr_in address;
    int server_handle;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    if ((server_handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("cannot create socket");  
        exit(0);
    }
    memset((char *) &address, 0, sizeof(address)); 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT); 
    if (bind(server_handle, (sockaddr *) &address, (socklen_t) addrlen) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(0); 
    }

    if (listen(server_handle, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("In listen");  
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    while(1) {
        std::cout << "\n+++++++ Waiting for new connection ++++++++\n\n"; 
        int client_handle;
        if ((client_handle = accept(server_handle, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t *) &addrlen))<0)
        { 
            perror("In accept");            
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);        
        }

        // read and respond to client request 
        char buffer[30000] = {0};
        int bytesRead = read(client_handle, buffer, 30000); 

        char * httptype = "HTTP/1.1 ";
        char * status = "200 \n";
        char * contenttype = "Content-Type: text/html \n";
        char * contentlength = "Content-Length: 21\n\n";
        char * body = "<h1>hello world!</h1>";


        write(client_handle, httptype, 9);
        write(client_handle, status, 5);
        write(client_handle, contenttype, 26);
        write(client_handle, contentlength, 20);
        write(client_handle, body, 21);

        std::cout << "------------------Response sent-------------------\n";

        close(client_handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome. Please share some code that you've already tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is indeed an interesting question, but not a nice one according to SO rule, so I think that you should read (again?) [ask]. We generally hope to have some code (ideally a [mcve]) to more easily reproduce what you have tried. And we expect that you have tried something... Here you should have shown code concatenating before writing to the socket an code doing multiple write to the socket, ideally with a `main` putting everything together. Don't be afraid anyway, first posts are generally not the best for most users!

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I added some code to show one of the options!

Comment: If you can easily organize buffering you should probaby do so, but note that TCP already has it, and already incorporates mechanisms such as the Nagle algorithm to coalesce outgoing sends, so the effect of not buffering isn't as bad as you might think.

Comment: NB The line terminator in HTTP is specified as `\r\n`, not `\n`.

Comment: @GrantReszczyk , it seems the scatter/gather IO is the solution you are searching for. For example, `writev` method (https://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) allows to send multiple buffers by a single method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send multiple buffers with a single `write` call you can use vectored IO (aka scatter/gather IO) as the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/writev) suggests:

```
char *str0 = "hello ";
char *str1 = "world\n";
struct iovec iov[2];
ssize_t nwritten;

iov[0].iov_base = str0;
iov[0].iov_len = strlen(str0);
iov[1].iov_base = str1;
iov[1].iov_len = strlen(str1);

nwritten = writev(STDOUT_FILENO, iov, 2);
```

Answer (score -1):

In fact it writing to a socket is not really different from writing to a file descriptor. And the `fwrite` function was introduced to the C library for a reason: `write` (be it to a TCP connection or to a file descriptor) involve a system call on common OS and a context change user/kernel. That context change has some overhead, mainly if you write small chunks of data.

On the other hand, if you write larger chunks of data in sizes that are close to the physical size for the underlying system call (disk buffer for a file descriptor, or max packet size for a network socket), the `fwrite` call or in your example the code concatenating char arrays will not really lower the system overhead and will just add some user code processing.

TL/DR: this depends on the average size of what you write. The smaller it is, the higher benefit of concatenating the date in larger chunks before writing. And remember: this is a low level optimization that should only be considered if you have identified a performance bottleneck or if the code could be used in a broadly distributed library.

Comment: It  is extremely different. Consider the Nagle algorithm, for a start.

Comment: @user207421: How is it different? Do you think that you can actually write to disk one char at a time? There are system buffer at driver level in both sides. Implementation is different because the underlying mechanismes are, but the overhead of context switching exists at both sides.